# Insert new line between each regexp match?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text like this:

```
characters      value ∆delta     

ABCDEABCDE      -3.663  [analyze]
EFGHEFGHEF      -1.937  [analyze]
IJKLIJKLIJ      2.137   [analyze]
```

and I want to extract the numeric values

I googled about regexp and came up with this perl one-liner

```
perl -p -i -e 's/[^0-9-.]//g' file.txt
```

which for you must look extremely bad, but it seems to work for me in this case.
Only problem is, the text file now looks like

```
-3.663-1.9372.137
```

but I want it to look like

```
-3.663
-1.937
2.137
```

How do I insert a new line between each match in this regexp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the newline to your character class

```
perl -p -i -e 's/[^0-9-.\n]//g' file.txt
```

This doesn't "add" a newline, it keeps the existing one. There are other ways to accomplish this based on columns rather than regex.

awk:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt > tmpfile.txt && mv tmpfile.txt file.txt
```

bash/sh:

```
while read -r _ data _; do
   echo "$data"
done < file.txt > tmpfile.txt
mv tmpfile.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/[^-\d.\n\r]+//g' file.txt
```

You can also try:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/[^-\d.]*(\-?[\d\.]+)[^-\d.]*/$1\n/g' file.txt
```

or if you text may contain `.` and `-` without numbers (e.g. `ABC-DEF.GHI -3.663  [analyze]`), then:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(?:[^-\d.]+|\-(?!\d)|\.(?!\d))*(\-?(?:\d?\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*))(?:[^-\d.]+|\-(?!\d)|\.(?!\d))*/$1\n/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tab-separated data, so let's take advantage of that for optimal results.

```
perl -i -F\\t -lanE'BEGIN { <>; <>; } say $F[2]' file.txt
```

If you data was simply whitespace separated, I would suggest

```
perl -i -lanE'BEGIN { <>; <>; } say $F[2]' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How would your solution work? -  I only changed `-pe` to `-lpe`:

```
 perl -i -lpe 's/[^0-9.-]//g' file.txt
```

This can be shortened to:

```
 perl -i -lpe's/[^--9]//g' file.txt
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" solution to your problem is to use the `-l` option, which will handle line endings for you. It will in your case add a newline to your print with the `-p` option.

```
perl -pi -le 's/[^0-9-.]//g' file.txt
```

However, this solution is destructive, in that the input file is destroyed, and it assumes that no other numbers, dashes and periods exist in the file. The latter will easily corrupt your data.

ikegami's solution to split on tabs or whitespace is the best, in my opinion. However, you can also extract the complete numbers with a regex:

```
perl -nlwe 'print /(-?[\d.]+)/' file.txt
```

This will extract the first string consisting of numbers and periods, with optional leading dash. If you want to save the output to a file, simply redirect it

```
perl -nlwe 'print /(-?[\d.]+)/' file.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. The scripts inserted a new line between the numbers, but didn't remove the empty lines in the document (e.g. the one empty line in my first example text file). At least that's how my test text file turned out. I googled how to remove empty lines, and although I'm not able to combine it, I now get what I want using two one-liners

```
perl -i -lpe's/[^--9]//g' file .txt
perl -pi -e "s/^\n//" file .txt
```